# c++ simple reading from registry problem

Tags: c++, windows, registry

platform- win.

Well i'm trying to get a value of a key named SunJavaUpdateSched but i'm getting
an error. i'm getting the second error, somehow i can open the key but can't get the value. So this is the code so far:

```
void dealWithRegistry()
{
 HKEY regkey1;
 char data[100];
 DWORD datasize = sizeof (data) / sizeof (char);
 LONG rc = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &regkey1);
 if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
 {
  cout << "there was a problem openning" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
  rc = RegGetValue (regkey1, NULL, L"SunJavaUpdateSched", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, (void*) data, &datasize);
  if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
  cout << "there was a problem getting the value" << endl;
  }
 }

 printf("%s\n", data);

}
```

Comment: Please use markdown (indent 4 spaces) code blocks instead of HTML `<code>` items -- the HTML screws up your code (by doing things like removing every `<` character...)

Comment: use GetLastError and find out what the problem is.

Comment: Everything is fine now, first time using the code option

Comment: @Alex: `RegGetValue` doesn't use `GetLastError`. It returns the error code directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the actual error value. You can look up the system error code which will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Note that `RegGetValue` is going to return a wide character string, not a character string, which means your variable using `char`s is going to give you garbage.

Couple issues with the code itself:

1. `dealWithRegistry` ... really? How about `ReadJavaUpdateSchedulerValue`?
2. `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (by definition).
3. In C++ you should be using `static_cast` here instead of the C style cast.
4. You aren't calling `RegCloseKey` anywhere!

Comment: You're probably not giving it a big enough buffer to store the data, then. "If the pvData buffer is too small to receive the value, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA."

Answer (score 1):

1. ERROR_MORE_DATA indicates that your data buffer is not big enought to receive the value. See the [example in the MSDN article on RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a recipe on how to allocate the buffer correctly.
2. Your use of `L"..."` literals suggests that your project is compiled as Unicode, which means that `char data[]` has to be `WCHAR data[]` (or `TCHAR data[]`).
3. The expression `sizeof (data) / sizeof (char)` should be written as `sizeof (data) / sizeof (data[0])`; this way it will stay correct regardless of the actual type with which `data` is declared. Also, MSVC standard library has a (nonstandard) macro `_countof` exactly for this purpose.